# How to column and row bind two ff_matrix

Tags: arrays, r, memory-management, matrix, bigdata

Suppose I have two `ff_matrix`, how do I column and row bind them?

```
require(ff);require(ffbase)
a <- ffbase:::as.ff_matrix.ffdf(as.ffdf(data.frame(rnorm(10))))
b <- ffbase:::as.ff_matrix.ffdf(as.ffdf(data.frame(rnorm(10))))
```

Nothing I've tried works (including `cbind` etc)

Answer (score 1):

`rbind.ffdf` is available through package ffbase. If you are not working with `ffdf` objects instead of `ff_matrix` objects, you can just `rbind` `ffdf` objects.

```
library(ffbase)
ff1 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*10),ncol=10)))
ff2 <- ff1
x <- rbind(ff1, ff1)
class(x)
[1] "ffdf"
nrow(x)
[1] 20
```

Comment: How about ff_matrix objects?

Comment: not implemented in ffbase/ff yet, I suggest you fill that as a feature request in https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues